# Determine if Form has focus in Visual Studio designer

Tags: visual-studio, forms, focus, windows-forms-designer

I'm really not sure how to start on this one. I need to know if the form has focus, which I do using `ContainsFocus` in code. However, this does not seem to work in the designer. Any suggestion?

Comment: It will never get focus in the designer.  The designer has the focus.

Comment: Yes, but the window chrome has an active/inactive state.

Comment: Are you trying to automate someting in the IDE during design? What are you trying to achieve by checking focus at desgin time?

Comment: I am trying to set a form drawing color depending on the frame state. This is particularly useful in Aero applications design.